# Инициализировать массив структуры другим массивом

Tags: c++

Инициализирую массив в структуре напрямую:

```
struct Array
{
  int arr3[3];
};
Array ar = { 1, 2, 3};
```

как проинициализировать **ar**  уже созданным массивом

```
   int as[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
   Array ar = ->?as?<- ;
```

Comment: Можно ли использовать при вашей логике программы указатели? Т.е. вместо `int arr3[3];` написать `int* arr3;` и дальше уже присвоить ему указатель на созданный и проинициализированный отдельно массив.

Comment: Никакой логики нет, просто интерес сократить выражение 'Array ar = {as[0], as[1], as[2]} ;'  до удобочитаемого например ` Array ar = &as;`

Answer (score 1):

То, что используется у Вас в примере, называется агрегатной инициализацией (см. [п.8.5.1.](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr) Стандарта).

Чтобы инициализировать `Array` уже созданным массивом, можно написать так:

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
Array ar = { a[0], a[1], a[2] };
```

Это не очень выразительно, но зато не требует изменять класс `Array`. Если же добавить конструктор, то можно сделать инициализацию более красиво (однако при этом класс перестанет быть тривиальным, и использовать агрегатную инициализацию уже будет нельзя):

```
struct Array
{
    int arr3[3];
    Array( int(&a)[3] ) : arr3 { a[0], a[1], a[2] } {} // добавили конструктор
};
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
Array ar = a; // теперь это работает
Array ar2 = { 1, 2, 3 }; // а это перестало работать
```

Чтобы обеспечить одновременно и возможность инициализации как в исходном примере, придется добавить ещё один конструктор:

```
Array( int a0, int a1, int a2 ) : arr3 { a0, a1, a2 } {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть хитрый способ :) - если эти массивы, как у вас, спрятаны в структуры.

**В этом случае** вызывается конструктор копирования [по умолчанию, если вы не определили свой]. Так что

```
struct Array
{
    int a[3];
};
Array a = {1, 2, 3};
Array b = a;
```

сработает. В случае простых массивов - надо заниматься копированием.

Comment: А если в структуре еще какие-то данные? Или два массива? Тогда тоже копировать нужно?

Comment: Увы, конструктор по умолчанию именно так и поступает - копирует все данные-члены.